# SQL Server: select without order

Tags: sql-server, select

I am using `where in` condition in SQL Server. I want to get result without order, because I gave a list into the 'where in' condition.

For example

```
select * from blabla where column in ('03.01.KO61.01410',
'03.02.A081.15002',
'03.02.A081.15016',
'03.02.A081.15003',
'02.03.A081.57105')
```

How can I do?

Comment: your query looks OK. What's the problem?

Comment: results should be in the order mentioned in my circumstances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to my experience, SQL Server randomly order the result set for WHERE-IN Clause if you does not specify how to order it.

So, if you want to order by your WHERE-IN conditions, you must define some data item to order it as you passed.  Otherwise, SQL Server will randomly order your resultset.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the rows returned such that they're in the same order as the items in your IN, you need to find some way to specify that in an ORDER BY clause - the only way to get SQL Server to define an order. E.g.:

```
select * from blabla where column in ('03.01.KO61.01410',
'03.02.A081.15002',
'03.02.A081.15016',
'03.02.A081.15003',
'02.03.A081.57105')
order by
CASE column
when '03.01.KO61.01410' then 1
when '03.02.A081.15002' then 2
when '03.02.A081.15016' then 3
when '03.02.A081.15003' then 4
when '02.03.A081.57105' then 5
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You're already doing it - if you don't explicitly specify an order by using `ORDER BY`, then there is no implied order.

If you want to totally randomize the output, you could add an `ORDER BY NEWID()` clause:

```
 SELECT (list of columns) 
 FROM dbo.blabla 
 WHERE column IN ('03.01.KO61.01410', '03.02.A081.15002',
                  '03.02.A081.15016', '03.02.A081.15003', '02.03.A081.57105')
 ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: No. I dont want sql ordering. Because I gave conditional list in where statement. It should be as where-in. But SQL orders it according to ASC automatically. Understand me?

Comment: The order of results returned by the RDBMS is undefined unless order by is used.  If nothing changes in terms of data, indexes, etc it is possible to receive results from the same query in the same order for quite some time.  And then one day something changes (data added, deleted or updated, indexed added/dropped, datafile is migrated to different disk, etc) and the order will change.  The order you are seeing in your result set is inherently 'unordered' in so far as one day it will be different.  Take a good look a marc_s's 'order by newid()' - it is close to a random order.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an autoincrement id in your table, use it in an order clause. And if you don't, consider adding one...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TYPE varchar20_list_type AS TABLE (
    id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    val VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

DECLARE @mylist varchar20_list_type
INSERT @mylist (val) VALUES
    ('03.01.KO61.01410'),
    ('03.02.A081.15002'),
    ('03.02.A081.15016'),
    ('03.02.A081.15003'),
    ('02.03.A081.57105')

SELECT
    *
FROM
    blabla
    JOIN @mylist AS t
    ON
        blabla.col = t.val
ORDER BY
    t.id
```

More information from http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

By the way, this can be easily done in PostgreSQL with VALUES: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-values.html